# Creating an array in React with objects created from two lists

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to take a json payload and plot it in a `react-table`. The required format for their table is (very specific and) the following: (this is the target format I'm trying to create)

```
  const rTableObj = [
    {'Col1': row1_col1, 'Col2': row1_col2, 'Col3': row1_col3},
    {'Col1': row2_col1, 'Col2': row2_col2, 'Col3': row2_col3},
    ...
  ]
```

The raw payload object, after the `fetch(url)` and `response.json` comes out as:

```
  rawPayload:
    Names: {0: "Rebecca", 1: "Sally", 2: "Sally", 3: "Charlie", ...}
    Nums: {0: 11, 1: 16, 2: 8, 3: 12, ...}
    Range: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, ...}
```

I can extract the column names, such that I'll have (in this example) `colNames = ['Names', 'Nums', 'Range']` and I can extract the values to their own object as

```
  vals: Array(3)
    0: {0: "Rebecca", 1: "Sally", 2: "Sally", 3: "Charlie", ...}
    1: {0: 11, 1: 16, 2: 8, 3: 12, ...}
    2: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, ...}
```

But everything I've tried (`.map(...)`, `[].concat(_.merge(...)`, etc.) doesn't get me to the target. I want to be able to send any payload to the mapper such that the properly formatted object is returned. For this example, that would look like this:

```
  const rTableObj = [
    {'Names': "Rebecca", 'Nums': 11, 'Range': 0},
    {'Names': "Sally", 'Nums': 16, 'Range': 1},
    ...
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Edited: so it works dynamically with different column names

```
rawPayload = {
  Names: { 0: "Rebecca", 1: "Sally", 2: "Sally", 3: "Charlie" },
  Nums: { 0: 11, 1: 16, 2: 8, 3: 12 },
  Range: { 0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3 },
  Age: { 0: 20, 1: 21, 2: 22, 3: 23 }
};

const tableMap = (rawPayload) => {
  let colNames = Object.keys(rawPayload);
  let length = Object.values(rawPayload[colNames[0]]).length

  let rTableObj = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var entry = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < colNames.length; j++) {
      var name = colNames[j];
      entry[name] = rawPayload[name][i];
    }
    rTableObj.push(entry);
  }
  return rTableObj;
};

console.log(tableMap(rawPayload));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - I'm trying to **not hardcode** the column names, and extract them, then use them. Is there any way to extract them from a colNames array in your function? Like `colNames = ['Names', 'Nums', 'Range']` ?

Comment: @WaveRider edited to handle column names dynamically

Comment: Looks good! One change needed: there's one dependency remaining on a column name in your line `let length = Object.values(rawPayload["Names"]).length;`, which can/should be changed to: `const length = Object.values(rawPayload[colNames[0]]).length;` ...and then you win the prize ;) ...Thank you!